# Jquery script to put title of image map area into text input form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this world map on the page and I can't seem to get this all working.  I've mapped the image correctly and made it responsive... but I can't get the title attribute from the map area that is clicked on to populate the region classed text field input. I'm not super knowledgeable in the whole jQuery area so any help would be amazing.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
     <img src="img/map.svg.png" class="map" width="2000" height="1057" alt="Insert Alt" usemap="#image_map" border="0">

<map name="image_map" id="image_map">
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords="" href="javascript:;" title="red"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 309,238" href="javascript:;" title="green"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 222,276, 202,295, 1,299, 6,124, 162,148, 160,236, 225,277" href="javascript:;" title="Alaska"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 54,474, 136,522, 74,558, 32,504, 57,474" href="javascript:;" title="Hawaii"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 167,149, 167,235, 263,324, 607,354, 639,201, 530,92, 169,148" href="javascript:;" title="Canada"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 251,330, 257,442, 415,485, 512,489, 607,358, 252,328" href="javascript:;" title="USA"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 298,458, 423,492, 473,511, 422,558, 297,480, 298,461" href="javascript:;" title="Mexico"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 429,557, 467,523, 524,584, 501,615, 431,561" href="javascript:;" title="Central America"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1052,267, 1116,354, 1086,411, 1101,427, 893,411, 880,236, 1056,268" href="javascript:;" title="Western Europe"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 547,568, 481,638, 494,1014, 619,1030, 786,666, 572,553, 546,567" href="javascript:;" title="South America"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 474,497, 512,548, 601,532, 550,496, 478,497" href="javascript:;" title="Carribean"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1026,822, 1140,785, 1137,849, 1044,881, 1024,821" href="javascript:;" title="South Africa"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 846,417, 1116,428, 1195,570, 1239,570, 1233,807, 1145,781, 1023,819, 958,635, 846,630, 847,412" href="javascript:;" title="Africa"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 807,173, 884,186, 863,223, 795,225, 811,165" href="javascript:;" title="Iceland"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 971,247, 1055,264, 1119,354, 1095,412, 1132,432, 1140,417, 1195,406, 1222,395, 1218,374, 1093,248, 1116,147, 1051,126, 973,180, 972,246" href="javascript:;" title="Eastern Europe"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1728,642, 1729,709, 1601,721, 1554,774, 1575,911, 1793,960, 1933,966, 1960,874, 1937,698, 1732,645" href="javascript:;" title="Australia"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1440,509, 1441,463, 1586,505, 1642,531, 1726,641, 1724,705, 1440,721, 1442,512" href="javascript:;" title="Southeast Asia"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1373,420, 1355,425, 1327,499, 1380,613, 1413,614, 1437,509, 1431,471, 1376,423" href="javascript:;" title="India"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1199,566, 1134,440, 1144,421, 1232,397, 1208,316, 1319,277, 1427,324, 1313,518, 1202,566" href="javascript:;" title="Middle East"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1439,318, 1379,415, 1493,469, 1608,508, 1693,376, 1644,291, 1431,319" href="javascript:;" title="China"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1725,348, 1771,368, 1670,472, 1659,447, 1725,352" href="javascript:;" title="Japan"/>
  <area shape="poly" class="region" data-toggle="tooltip" coords=" 1154,23, 1099,245, 1187,315, 1331,271, 1423,314, 1658,286, 1700,365, 1747,347, 1808,353, 1988,212, 1986,125, 1542,7" href="javascript:;" title="Russian"/>
</map>
</div>
</div>
<div class="regionspacing">
  <label for="region">Region</label>
  <input type="text" id="region" name="region" class="form-control input-md">
</div>

         <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
        </script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger: 'hover','placement': 'top'});
        $(function(){
    $('area').live('click', function() {
        $("#region").val($(this).attr('title'));
    });

});
        </script>
```

here's the link to the site itself, it's running new bootstrap... www.zoomglobaltravel.com/perfect.html  (the region field isn't on there yet..)

Please Help :?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#image_map').on('click', 'area', function (e) {
    $('#region').val(e.target.title);
});
```

Basically, you attach a click event listener to all `<area>`s in `#image_map`. In this listener you get the `title` attribute of the clicked area and set it to the value of the `#region` input box.